# ValueError:Layer conv1d was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor.All inputs to the layer should be tensors

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, sequential, word-embedding, tf.keras

I built this model and it was working fine.

```
###Building the Model. 
input_layer= Embedding(num_words, 300, input_length=35, weights=[embedding_matrix],trainable=True)
conv_blocks = []
filter_sizes = (2,3,4)
for fx in filter_sizes:
    conv_layer= Conv1D(100, kernel_size=fx, activation='relu', data_format='channels_first')(input_layer)
    maxpool_layer = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4)(conv_layer)
    flat_layer= Flatten()(maxpool_layer)
    conv_blocks.append(flat_layer)
#conc_layer=concatenate(conv_blocks, axis=1)
conc_layer=Concatenate(axis=-1)([conv_blocks])
graph = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=conc_layer)

model = Sequential()
model.add(graph)
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

I recently reran it and I'm getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/am/embassy/vol/x6/jetbrains/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/191.6183.50/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/am/embassy/vol/x6/jetbrains/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/191.6183.50/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/PycharmProjects/untitled/WordEmb.py", line 128, in <module>
conv_layer= Conv1D(100, kernel_size=fx, activation='relu', data_format='channels_first')(input_layer)   #filters=100, kernel_size=3
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 414, in __call__
self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 285, in assert_input_compatibility
str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the layer '
ValueError: Layer conv1d_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.embeddings.Embedding'>. Full input: [<keras.layers.embeddings.Embedding object at 0x7fae61513c18>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

I have checked similar post here but none is very similar to mine. I have tried their suggestions like adding the axis to Concatenate() or using concatenate instead but nothing changed.

```
[embedding_matrix] is a 2d array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is thrown because `input_layer` is `Layer` and not `Tensor`.
You are passing `Embedding` "layer" as input to `Conv1D`, in this case you have not provided any input to embedding layer.

Change this one:

```
input_layer= Embedding(num_words, 300, input_length=35, weights=[embedding_matrix],trainable=True)
```

and add input tensor to this layer:

```
input_layer= Embedding(num_words, 300, input_length=35, weights=[embedding_matrix],trainable=True)(input_tensor)
```

Also I think you are trying to `Concatenate` outputs from three separate filters, if that is the case then:

```
conc_layer=Concatenate(axis=-1)([conv_blocks])
graph = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=conc_layer)
```

this part would come outside loop.

Comment: oh. right. but what will be the content of `input_tensor.` Yes, thanks the `concatenate` inside the loop is a typo.

Comment: _input_tensor_ will be actual input to the model, which will be passed to Embedding layer, and that same input will be given as _inputs_ in _Model()_

Comment: I don't clearly understand this `input_tensor will be the actual input to the model`. I tried `input_tensor=Input(shape=1,300)` but that isn't working. i'm getting another error i cant decipher 'ValueError: Layer weight shape (16513, 300) not compatible with provided weight shape (16514, 300)'. The actual input to the model is introduced at the `model.fit` stage. Is there some material you could point me to. Thanks.

Comment: sorry my bad! _input_tensor_ will be tensor same shape as actual input to the model. What is shape of the input you are passing while ```model.fit```?

Comment: The shape of the input im passing is `(18587,35)`. I have tried that too but it keeps giving the same error in my previous comment.  So basically, I have an embedding matrix of shape `(16514,300)` where each row is 300d vector representing a single word. My train set contains 18587 sentences each with a maximum of 35 words.

Comment: @Kosi If your input has shape (18587, 35) in that case is 18587 is number of examples I assume? In that case ```input_tensor = Input(shape=(35,))``` works.

Comment: For error you mentioned is comment: since your embedding matrix is ```(16514,300)``` your ```num_words``` should also be 16514

Comment: *facepalm, that makes sense. thank you. It is now resolved.